# Countable set can be listed in a sequence

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $S$ be a countable set, i.e. exists bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $S$. Why elements of $S$ can be listed in a sequence?

**EDIT:** I guess that bijection is not crucial. It's sufficient that mapping (namely $f$) is surjective, i.e. for any $T\in S$ exists $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $T=f(n)$. Hence $S$ can be arrabged in sequence $\{f(1), f(2), \dots\}$. Am I right?

Comment: Your edit is almost correct: The set $\{f(1), f(2), \ldots \}$ is (in general) not a sequence. So you should write $(f(1), f(2), \ldots )$ instead.

Comment: @Stefan, Why it is not sequence?

Comment: Well, by the definition of *sequence*. A sequence respects order and multiplicity. E.g. the sequences $(1, 3, 4, 3)$, $(1, 4, 3, 3)$ and $(1,3,4)$ are all different, while $\{1,3,4,3\} = \{1,4,3,3\} = \{1,3,4\}$ as sets.

Comment: In Russian literature we sometime use $\{x_i\}$ for notion of sequence

Comment: Okay, I didn't know that. But anyways, notation doesn't matter as long as you know (and communicate!) its intended interpretation. [That's not entirely true - but discussing *good* notation here is blatantly off-topic.]

Comment: @Stefan, Why in some books in definition of countable set ones write surjectivity and another bijective?

Comment: Because we can prove that these definitions are equivalent. In fact, in one of my comments below my answer I outlined a proof of this fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sequence $s = (x_{n} \mid n \in \mathbb N)$ is 'the same' as a
function $f \colon \mathbb N \to \operatorname{ran}(s)$. Depending on
your exact definitions of *sequence* and *function* they may not
be the same set (using my definition, they are actually the same set),
but they are certainly mutually definable. I.e. given a sequence
$s = (x_{n} \mid n \in \mathbb N)$ we may define a function $f \colon
\mathbb N \to \operatorname{ran}(s)$ by letting $f(n) := s_{n}$ and
conversely, given a function $f \colon \mathbb N \to X$, we may define
a sequence $s =(x_{n} \mid n \in \mathbb N)$ by letting $s_{n} :=
f_{n}$. This way, converting a function to a sequence and then converting the resulting sequence to a function gives back the original function and likewise if we start with a sequence, convert it into a function and back to a sequence.

In particular, given a bijection $f \colon \mathbb N \to X$, we may
list all elements of $X$ via the sequence $(f(n) \mid n \in \mathbb N)$.

Comment: But I guess that you don't answer to my questions. I am asking why it's elements can be listed in a sequence? And why bijection is crucial? Can we replace it by surjection?

Comment: @RFZ Yes, a surjection is enough (as long as $S$ is infinite). But I don't understand your first question: Stefan's answer seems satisfactory to me. What is missing?

Comment: I can't understand why from being function bijection we make consequence that it can be listed in a sequence

Comment: @RFZ Yes, in order for the sequence to list all elements of $X$, it suffices that the function you start with is surjective. (However, it may then list a given element multiple times.)

Comment: Why we need in injectivity?

Comment: For $X$ to be listed in a sequence means that there is a sequence $(s_i \mid i \in I)$ (some people require $I = \mathbb N$, other's don't - you'd have to your definition) such that for all $x \in X$ there is some $i \in I$ such that $x = s_i$. The sequence that I constructed does exactly this, provided that $f$ is surjective.

Comment: @RFZ We don't. Even if $f$ is not injective, the constructed sequence 'lists' $X$. If you don't want any element of $X$ to appear multiple times, we can alter the construction to ensure this. Let $s_n$ be $f(k)$ were $k \in \mathbb N$ is the least natural number such that $f(k) \not \in \{s_m \mid m < n\}$. (This relies on the recursion theorem - which is provable in ZFC.)

Comment: The last question: Why in surjectivity xome element can appear multiple times?

Comment: @RFZ A function $f \colon A \to B$ is surjective iff for every $b \in B$ there is *at least* one $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = b$. It could very well be that there are multiple $a$'s that all map to $b$. There may for example be seven distinct elements $a_1, a_2, \ldots a_7$ such that $f(a_1)=f(a_2) = \ldots f(a_7) = b$. In this case, the element $b$ would appear at least $7$ times in our sequence.

Answer (score 3):

Because *the way we formalize the concept of "infinite sequence"* in set theory is as a function with domain $\mathbb N$.

Therefore "$S$ can be listed in a sequence" means, **by definition**, that there is a function $f:\mathbb N\to S$ that hits each element of $S$ -- and hits it exactly once, because we suppose every element of $S$ to appear only once in the sequence.

But such an $f$ is exactly a bijection between $\mathbb N$ and $S$.